# What is the .iplt section in ARM assembly?

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm trying to understand the disassembly of a program of mine. It contains a .iplt section which seems like a lookup table.

Are there any resources online that goes into detail about what this section is used for and how?

Comment: PLT is known as the procedure-linkage-table and it includes lookup information regarding where functions of linked libraries are loaded into memory. The `.iplt` is undoubtedly related to the same concept, though I'm unsure about the `i` part.

Comment: What toolchain did you use to build the executable, for what OS?  e.g. GCC + GNU Binutils to make an ARM Linux executable?  Or AArch64 macOS with clang + the macOS linker, if you didn't mean 32-bit ARM?  I assume not a bare-metal thing, since dynamic linking wouldn't be a thing in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### PLT and GOT

PLT is "procedure linkage table". The table entries of PLT are small sequence of codes that jump to a specific address read from GOT (global offset table). GOT is another table that stores the function address loaded at run time (by loader).

PLT + GOT are used for shared library.

### `iplt` and Indirect function

`iplt` section is the PLT specifically for "indirect function (ifunc)"[[1]](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/GNU_IFUNC)[[2]](https://maskray.me/blog/2021-01-18-gnu-indirect-function).
An indirect function is provided with multiple implementations. And a resolver function would be called to determine which one is used **at runtime**.

A common example is that, in glibc, there are different implementations for ARM's `memcpy()`. Glibc [uses ifunc](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/4290aed05135ae4c0272006442d147f2155e70d7/sysdeps/arm/armv7/multiarch/ifunc-memcpy.h#L25) to select neon implementation if the CPU supports neon extension.

ifunc uses similar mechanism as shared library. `iplt` entries are small sequence of codes that load function address from GOT and jump to the function. The function address in GOT is filled by resolver to the chosen implementation.